# docker container shuts down immediately

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

i am facing a problem...i have a spring boot app that i want to containerize..i built my image and when i run the container i get this message:

```
[SpringApplicationShutdownHook] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigAppl
icationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
```

has anyone faced something similar to that?i can't figure out what is the problem..

this is what i have on my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ADD ./target/registereureka.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

i can't figure what is causing the problem

Comment: Please read whole container output. Probably there is an error message in it.

Comment: Does running the `registereureka.jar` file directly (not in Docker) work?

Comment: What are your dependencies? What does the APP do, is there something in there that keeps the app alive, like tomcat? How are you building the jar?

Comment: Hello and thank you all for looking at my question.


gdomo: there is nothing else wrong in the container outpup, everything before SpringApplicationShutdownHook says that container started


the last output before shutdown is:  DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages'
18:04:33.471 [main] INFO com.registereureka.registereureka.RegistereurekaApplication - Started RegistereurekaApplication in 1.582 seconds (JVM running for 2.53)

Comment: rob spoor: yes it works, i run the app in intellij and it works

Comment: m deinum: it is just a eureka server app, nothing else...i have to make 4 spring boot apps (eureka server and 4 clients) and i need to put each one in docker containers

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code. Kindly try it:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk
ADD target/employee-crud-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 9003
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

I think you are adding "**/**" along with **app.jar** in Entrypoint and it is not able to find the jar file. Try to remove **"/"** first and if it doesn't work, take my code as a reference.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer...unfortunately the problem still remains, i tried it without the / and still got the SpringApplicationShutdownHook...i tried to follow you code example but still the same issue